# Sum together certain values in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working in python, and have a dataframe(df), which includes the column 'COUNTERPARTYNAME'. There are different counterparties in this column, like 'A', 'B', 'C', etc... There is also another column called MTM, which is made up of numbers.

```
COUNTERPARTYNAME                   NPV          
0     A                            90                

1     B                            85                    

2     A                            130                     

3     C                            90    

4     B                            105

5     A                            75
...

...
```

Essentially, I'm looking to add a column to my dataframe that would have the sum of all the NPV's for the corresponding COUNTERPARTYNAME in that row.

My expected result would be like so:

```
    COUNTERPARTYNAME               NPV                 SUM(NPV)      
0     A                            90                  295

1     B                            85                  190  

2     A                            130                 295 

3     C                            90                  90

4     B                            105                 190

5     A                            75                  295
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['SUM(NPV)'] = df.groupby('COUNTERPARTYNAME')['NPV'].transform('sum')
```